# Convert unorganised data to parseable format in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have this code and it has every element of this code has a meaning.

```
 PRICING OPTION 11                 TOTAL AMOUNT             40009 INR
ADT                               TAX INCLUDED 
1   UK    933  K  15FEB DEL BOM   1515  1725    TH   320       SRCI0
2   NH    830  S  15FEB BOM NRT   2000  0715 +  TH   788       SRCI0
3   NH    829  V  19FEB NRT BOM   1115  1825    MO   788       VRCI0
4   UK    988  K  19FEB BOM DEL   2045  2300    MO   320       VRCI0
´BOOKª          +TQ                                                      D  R  +8

 PRICING OPTION 12                 TOTAL AMOUNT             40376 INR
ADT                               TAX INCLUDED 
1   NH @ 6431  S  15FEB DEL BOM   1500  1715    TH   73H       SRCI0
2   NH    830  S  15FEB BOM NRT   2000  0715 +  TH   788       SRCI0
3   NH    827  W  19FEB NRT DEL   1715  0005 +  MO   788       WRCI0
´BOOKª          +TQ
```

I tried to use python to extract each line and split spaces for each line. The problem is that the number of spaces can be different in different lines for the same element.

Is there a better way to extract elements out of this code except for finding spaces?

Comment: `split()` method actually collapses multiple delimiters so that should not be a problem. Also, `pandas` can read [fixed width column tables](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_fwf.html), you can try it (though different 'BOOK' blocks will require manual handling anyway).

Comment: Will this help? `import re;print [re.split(' +',line) for line in a.split('\n')] `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex split for this purpose!

```
>>> import re
>>> [re.split(' +',line) for line in a.split('\n')] 
[['PRICING', 'OPTION', '11', 'TOTAL', 'AMOUNT', '40009', 'INR'], ['ADT', 'TAX', 'INCLUDED', ''], ['1', 'UK', '933', 'K', '15FEB', 'DEL', 'BOM', '1515', '1725', 'TH', '320', 'SRCI0'], ['2', 'NH', '830', 'S', '15FEB', 'BOM', 'NRT', '2000', '0715', '+', 'TH', '788', 'SRCI0'], ['3', 'NH', '829', 'V', '19FEB', 'NRT', 'BOM', '1115', '1825', 'MO', '788', 'VRCI0'], ['4', 'UK', '988', 'K', '19FEB', 'BOM', 'DEL', '2045', '2300', 'MO', '320', 'VRCI0'], ['´BOOKª', '+TQ', 'D', 'R', '+8'], [''], ['', 'PRICING', 'OPTION', '12', 'TOTAL', 'AMOUNT', '40376', 'INR'], ['ADT', 'TAX', 'INCLUDED', ''], ['1', 'NH', '@', '6431', 'S', '15FEB', 'DEL', 'BOM', '1500', '1715', 'TH', '73H', 'SRCI0'], ['2', 'NH', '830', 'S', '15FEB', 'BOM', 'NRT', '2000', '0715', '+', 'TH', '788', 'SRCI0'], ['3', 'NH', '827', 'W', '19FEB', 'NRT', 'DEL', '1715', '0005', '+', 'MO', '788', 'WRCI0'], ['´BOOKª', '+TQ', '']]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions:

```
import re
final_data = [list(filter(lambda x:x, re.split('\s+', i))) for i in data.split('\n')][1:-1]
```

Output:

```
[['PRICING', 'OPTION', '11', 'TOTAL', 'AMOUNT', '40009', 'INR'], ['ADT', 'TAX', 'INCLUDED'], ['1', 'UK', '933', 'K', '15FEB', 'DEL', 'BOM', '1515', '1725', 'TH', '320', 'SRCI0'], ['2', 'NH', '830', 'S', '15FEB', 'BOM', 'NRT', '2000', '0715', '+', 'TH', '788', 'SRCI0'], ['3', 'NH', '829', 'V', '19FEB', 'NRT', 'BOM', '1115', '1825', 'MO', '788', 'VRCI0'], ['4', 'UK', '988', 'K', '19FEB', 'BOM', 'DEL', '2045', '2300', 'MO', '320', 'VRCI0'], ['´BOOKª', '+TQ', 'D', 'R', '+8'], [], ['PRICING', 'OPTION', '12', 'TOTAL', 'AMOUNT', '40376', 'INR'], ['ADT', 'TAX', 'INCLUDED'], ['1', 'NH', '@', '6431', 'S', '15FEB', 'DEL', 'BOM', '1500', '1715', 'TH', '73H', 'SRCI0'], ['2', 'NH', '830', 'S', '15FEB', 'BOM', 'NRT', '2000', '0715', '+', 'TH', '788', 'SRCI0'], ['3', 'NH', '827', 'W', '19FEB', 'NRT', 'DEL', '1715', '0005', '+', 'MO', '788', 'WRCI0'], ['´BOOKª', '+TQ']]
```

Comment: I don't get it `final_data = [line.split() for line in data.split('\n')][1:-1]` produces exact same output. Why do you need regex for?